# Joomla User Registration Component

Tags: joomla3.4

I am new to this forum and also new in using joomla. I have a joomla3.4 site where I would like add extra fields to user registration form. I have searched over this for entirely two days now and got few options like
1)Override registration component
2)modifyng and adding new fileds in root/libraries/joomla/user/user.php
3)using  extensions

I am not a joomla expert, hence 1st and 2nd option is bit more complicated for me, since it also invloves  core files getting rewritten during joomla upgrade.

I am left with the 3rd option, which makes use of other 3rd party extension. I am not sure how does this 3rd party plugins work. Do they automatically insert the extra fileds data into joomla user table or where it will be stored?
I would like to use captcha-recaptcha into the registration form. 
Please guide me on some good extensions(freeor paid) that I can use for registration form.

Your help and support is appreciated.

Thanks,
mds2907

Answer (score 0):

In theory you should be able to just enable the plugin "User - Profile" that you already have and select the fields you want added to the form. That's not actually working for me on Joomla 3.4 but that may be due to a different issue with some additional symptoms that I'm debugging ([Joomla 3.x - Two factor authentication disabled but still working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32416701/1745001)).