# Joomla 3.x - Two factor authentication disabled but still working

Tags: joomla

In my Joomla 3.x I have disabled every single plugin related to Two factor authentication, but it's still showing up in the frontend form when the user tries to login.

Comment: This is more of a configuration question than a coding question. You'd be better off asking on the Joomla SE site [joomla.se]. But I will say this is not true for me.

Comment: I've never had a Joomla question answered in that site. And yes, it's true.

Comment: Wow that's crazy.  Did you try the Joomla forums? Is it possible your template has a layout override for the login?

Comment: Yeah, maybe it's that. I got like 4 two factor plugins and they are disabled, but the thing still appears. I'll check the template

Comment: No can do. Not the template. I've checked the template and all the plugins related to that, nothing. What it could be now? Perhaps something else in the site, maybe something in the Global Settings?

Comment: Are the plugins disable in the plugin manager or are they disabled in the extensions manage?

Comment: They're disabled in both.

Comment: Does logging in using 2FA actually work? Or is it that the field displays but the plugins don't work?

Comment: `I've never had a Joomla question answered in that site` >> You don't appear to have a profile on JSE. I would strongly suggest you do ask there

Comment: Maybe because I use a different account with a different email?

Comment: Elin, logging works.

Comment: I'm having this same problem and was just about to post a question. Any luck with a solution? I've been googling for answers and checking and rechecking every plugin, module, template file, etc. for 3 days now and I am completely stumped. I'm on Joomla 3.4.3 btw.

Answer (score 0):

Purge/clean cache:

System -> clear cache

Exensions -> extensions manager -> manage -> refresh cache

Check again if plugin is disabled.

Comment: I have the cache turned off.